# Enable Drop Down Macro for Protected Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, protected

I have created a macro that allows a user to select an option from a dropdown list which unhides selected rows that corresponds with their selection. The problem is when I protect the sheet I get the following error "Run-time error '1004'" when I select an option for the drop down list. I need this sheet to be protected so the user cannot touch the data sets shown. Here is a sample code (original version is very long):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C15"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
Case Is ="Option 1"
Rows("17:75").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Case Is ="Option 2"
Rows("17:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Select
End If
End Sub
```

I've been reading other threads and I've come across a few options that said I need to Unprotect and Protect my sheet but I'm not to sure how to add this to the code above. And if this is the best option for what I am trying to accomplish

Option 1

```
Sub UnprotectAll()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Next sh
End Sub

Sub ProtectAll()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Protect Password:=yourPassword
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Option 2 - Adding this code somewhere below

```
UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

Any suggestions in how I can accomplish this? And what the full code would look like?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ExcelNoob I’ve made the following assumptions based on your question:

1. Only the active sheet is relevant
2. You formatted cell C15 as not Locked (when the sheet is unprotected, right click C15 /format/protection and uncheck ‘locked’ & ‘hidden’
3. You have indicated the correct rows you want hidden or not (seem a bit odd?)
4. There are only 2 options

That being the case, the minimum code below will do what you ask.  If you want to use a specific password, just put it between the double quotation marks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Range("C15"), Target) Is Nothing Then

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""

    If Range("C15").Value = "Option 1" Then
        Rows("17:75").Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("C15").Value = "Option 2" Then
        Rows("17:28").Hidden = False
    End If
    
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: adding the ActiveSheet.Unprotect and Protect to the top and bottom of the code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As per above, but if you don't want to protect/unprotect, put your drop down in a form and use :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheet1.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

Where "password" is changed to whatever password you want.